# ¿Cómo puedo hacer videos responsive con css grid?

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, css-grid-layout

Estoy usando css grid para hacer una landing page, el header tiene display: grid; y dentro del header esta el video(iframe). Estoy tratando de hacerlo responsive pero no puedo por más que intenté. ¿Me podrían ayudar si no fuera molestia?

```css
.c-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  background-color: #f33e67;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  /*font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;*/ }
  .c-header__item:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: RGB(0 0 0/30%) 2px 0px 2px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white; }
  .c-header__item:nth-child(2) {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: RGB(0 0 0/30%) 2px 0px 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black; }
  .c-header__item:nth-child(3) {
    font-weight: 800;
    text-shadow: RGB(0 0 0/30%) 2px 0px 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white; }
  .c-header__container-video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0; }
  .c-header__video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
```

```html
<header class="c-header">
        <p class="c-header__item">COMIENZA TU PROPIO NEGOCIO FLORAL SIN ALTAS INVERSIONES DE DINERO Y DOMINA LAS TÉCNICAS FLORALES SIN NECESIDAD DE SER UNA UNA EXPERTA</p>
        <p class="c-header__item">ADVERTENCIA ️: ¡Estas a un paso de descubrir el método innovador que te permitirá GENERAR INGRESOS 
            creando LUJOSOS ARREGLOS FLORALES , y eso no es todo , también te permitirá emprender un negocio rentable de alta demanda !</p>
        <p class="c-header__item">Mira el Video Hasta el Final</p>
        <div class="c-header__container-video">
            <iframe class="c-header__video"
                    src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/706660059?h=757d719681&portrait=0&byline=0&title=0"
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Prueba quitando el `relative` y `absolute` de tu video y también el `height: 100%`, en todo caso, ¿Cómo quieres que sea tu resultado esperado?

Comment: @Cris223511.dev hola, también hice lo mismo y el resultado fue el video pero en miniatura, lo que quiero es que se adapte al contenedor. ¿puedes ayudarme?